# Is there a work where a spacecraft lands using a skycrane like the Mars Science Laboratory (Curiousity)?

Tags: spaceship, space

I'm just asking whether a book, film, comic or other work of art has had a spacecraft land using a skycrane mechanism. Has someone though of this before the public was told how it would be done?

I know similar situations existed where an invention was pre-empted by science fiction works, e.g. the geostationary satellite or the Internet. The first was conceived by Arthur C. Clarke, and the second was conceptualized by a Dutch or Belgian (Flemish?) scientist (I don't know his name), but he could not speak any well-known language like French, German, or English and his works were only in Dutch so no one bothered to read them. He was also not much aware of electronics nor digital technology, so his works were theoretical. It was about connecting people in homes to the books in the libraries (by telephone?)... along this lines I don't remember much more.

So did anything like that exist on the subject of spacecraft landings by skycranes?

Comment: Some computer games used this concept, even before the Curiosity was developed. M.A.X. for example, and maybe even C&C but I'm not sure with the last one.

Comment: This is a pretty straightforward list question, which are not allowed per the [FAQ](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Strange, 4 votes on my question, and also on answer and two times starred yet it is disallowed by rules... -> Well maybe there is something wrong with them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified LAAT Gunships from Star Wars, the Space Marine Thunderhawk Gunship from Warhammer 40,000, and the Pelican from Halo all can have vehicles attached to them, and often deploy the vehicles from a few feet above the ground. All of the gunships can deploy from space. They don't quite do the skycrane maneuver, but it's rather similar.